# Why does my infant burps many times

Tags: infant

My child (2 months old) keeps burping multiple times after feed, he has a first big burp and then multiple small burps, due to this his sleep gets interrupted. This is usually early morning and afternoon and not at night, plz advise.

Answer (score 3):

From what I've heard this is not unusual. He may be swallowing some air when feeding quickly.

You could try putting him upright with his head on your shoulder after a feed and gently patting or rubbing his back to get the wind out before sleep.

Answer (score 2):

Babies that young haven't yet learned to eat (drink) without swallowing some of air, and they lack the ability to force a burp on their own like older children and adults; therefore, you have to burp them to release the air they swallow.  It's different with each child - some have no problems while others may be difficult to burp.

The problem can be worse if the air finds its way past the stomach and into the intestinal tract.  This could cause some abdominal discomfort and "gassiness", which could be distressing to your child.  That's why it is so important to burp them immediately after feeding.  Also, laying a child on his/her back without being burped could increase the chance of spitting up and aspirating some of the vomit.  It's usually not dangerous, but vomit in the lungs can cause problems.  It's best to ensure as much air as possible is forced out of their stomach by burping them.

As for different times of day, I don't know.  Perhaps (as the other poster suggested) it's a matter of swallowing more air when feeding early in the morning because of increased hunger, but that's just speculation.